# Prove that exponential functions grow faster than polynomial

Tags: calculus, functions

I am asked to proof that being $r$ and $s$ two known fixed real numbers such that $r > 0$ and $s > 1$,
there exists $n_0$ such that for every $n  > n_0$ this happens:

$n^r < ks^n$ where $k$ is any real positive number.

I can't find a value for $n$ that makes the statement true.

Thanks a lot, I have been stuck for a while, any help is welcome.

Bye!

Comment: Would you mind editing a little? Almost read "there exist $n_0$" as "there exist no"

Comment: Sorry i didn't know how to put it the nice way. A gentle soul did it instead

Comment: This statement is essentially saying "an exponential grows faster than a power". Try picking arbitrary values of $r$ and $s$ and treat $n$ as a variable. Suppose $s = e$ and $r = 1$. Is there a point $n_0$ at which $n_0 = ke^{n_0}$? What about to the right of that point?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^r}{ks^{n+1}} \frac{ks^n}{n^r} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac1n)^r \frac{1}{s} = \frac1s < 1
$$

By proving that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} < 1$, with $x_n := \frac{n^r}{ks^n}$, we know that the sequence $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$ converges to $0$. Thus, we prove that $ks^n$ grows faster than $n^r$, so there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > n_0 \implies n^r < ks^n$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, helped me a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome! Remember, it's easier to prove that $n_0$ *exists*, rather than finding its value. ;-)

Comment: Plus, if you want to, try to find a title to this question that can help people with problems as similar as yours. It would be nice!