# How can I prove limit of $n^k$ over $c^n$ is 0?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> How can I prove that 
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^k}{c^n}=0\ ?
> $$
>   I know it is true by intuition, but I do not know how to prove it.
>   Here $c\gt1, k\ge1$.

---

BACKGROUND

I am learning time complexity theory and I couldn't find the proof of this in [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). It just shows that time complexity of $c^n$ is always greater than $n^k$. Therefore, I cannot understand the proof which uses derivatives like L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: The way the topics are arranged in certain textbooks, the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^k}{c^n} = 0$ is computed much before the derivative of $c^x$.  If Privacy is using such a textbook, then answers using derivatives will not help him.  This type of thing may be a reason not to answer such questions until the attempts are shown, telling us what the background of the asker is.

Comment: @GEdgar I edited

Comment: This is due to exponential functions, with a base $c \gt 1$, always eventually grow faster than any polynomial, e.g., $n^k$ in your case. This issue was asked in [Prove that exponential functions grow faster than polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933754/prove-that-exponential-functions-grow-faster-than-polynomial), with a fairly basic answer provided which doesn't use L'Hopital's rule or anything like that.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You may proceed for example as follows:

- $c > 1 \Rightarrow c = 1+p$ with $p > 0$

The binomial formula gives for $n \geq 1$

- $c^n = (1+p)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}p^i \Rightarrow c^n > \binom{n}{i}p^i$ for each $i = 0,\ldots , n$

Now, you can estimate as follows for $n > k$:

\begin{eqnarray*} 0\leq \frac{n^k}{c^n}
& = & \frac{n^k}{(1+p)^n}\\
& < & \frac{n^k}{\binom{n}{k+1}p^{k+1}}\\
& = & \frac{n^k\cdot (k+1)!}{\underbrace{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}_{k \; factors} \cdot (n-k) \cdot p^{k+1}} \\
& < & \frac{n^k\cdot (k+1)!}{(n-k)^{k+1} \cdot p^{k+1}}\\
& = & \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{(k+1)!}{(1-\frac{k}{n})^{k+1} \cdot p^{k+1}}\\
& \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} & 0 \cdot \frac{(k+1)!}{p^{k+1}} = 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, let $k$ be an integer (or take $k$ to be floor[$k+1$].  Apply L'Hopital's rule $k$ times:

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{n^k}{c^n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{k!}{(\ln c)^k c^n} = 0.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Set $u_n= \dfrac{n^k}{c^n}$ and calculate $\;\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$ to find an upper bound of the ratio for $n$ large.

Answer (score 0):

[L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), applied to this case, says that for $f(n) = n^k$ and $g(n) = c^n$, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n) = \infty$ and both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)}\ .  $$

Thus, after applying L'Hôpital's rule $k$ times you get:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{k!}{(\ln c)^k c^n} = 0\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Two hints/ideas: try Stolz-Cesaro or consider the *series* with your expression as general term. If converges, the g.t. -> 0.