# Prove that $n^k = {\cal O }(c^n)$

Tags: functions, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $k\geq 1, c>1$. I want to prove that $n^k = {\cal
>  O }(c^n)$, that is, $\exists n_0, b>0 \ s.t. \ \forall n\geq n_0, \
>  n^k\leq b c^n$

I'm struggling to prove this result, now I'm just trying to use induction to prove $\log_c (n^k/b) \leq n$, for some constants $n_0,b>0$, but this is not going well. Basically if I could prove this statement the rest will be very easy. Any sugsestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933754/prove-that-exponential-functions-grow-faster-than-polynomial, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154844/how-can-i-prove-limit-of-nk-over-cn-is-0?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @stange I will check

Comment: Why do you need $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @user10354138 I placed additional info, it is not from the problem, sry.